# Комбинаторика с похожими буквами между алфовитами

Tags: c#, .net, алгоритм

Например, есть буквы, которые похожи между русским и латинским алфавитами:
а,Н и т д...

Есть некоторый словарь.

Есть некоторая БД, где информация могла быть введена некорректно => если выполнять поиск по словарю, то его можно будет не найти.

Нужно перебрать все комбинации похожих латинских и кириллических символов.

Например, дано слово Носорог.(Надуманный пример)

Нужно сгенерировать последовательности(черный выделена латиница):

**Н**осорог
Н**о**сорог
Нос**о**рог
Носор**о**г
**Но**сорог

Можете подсказать абстрактный алгоритм для решения этой задачи?

Первое, что приходит на ум- это создать словарь и в него записать позиции символов, которые я собираюсь менять.

Далее пока не знаю в какую сторону двигаться.

Comment: А зачем вам все варианты. какова конечная цель. Я так вижу, что если надо найти такие слова, то простой регуляркой ищем слова состоящие из двух видов букв. Если надо реальные слова найти, то приводим все буквы к одному виду и ищем (в словаре по которому ищем, возможно то же приводим все к одним буквам)

Comment: Имхо никаких генераций ничего не надо. Надо писать функцию сравнения 2 строк посимвольно, и если 2 символа из одного семейства похожих символов, то они равны

Comment: Правильно. Напишите Comparer решающий вашу задачу.

Comment: @tym32167, не охота весь словарь грузить в память и построчно перебирать. Быстрее будет к базе запросы пулять, так как профит от индексов будет.

Comment: @Mike, думаю, что в этом есть смысл. Создам поисковое поле в словаре, которое приведено к одному виду символов, а само слово так же буду приводить к одному виду.

Comment: Если вам надо профит от индексов, то заводите в таблице словаря ещё одно поле - для нормализованного значения. В этом нормализованном значении заменяйте все похожие символы на базовый (например, все не-латинские о на латинскую о), и по этому нормализованному значению ищите с нормализованным критерием поиска

Comment: Сами меня опередили :)

Comment: Задача полностью аналогична поиску с игнорированием регистра и решается теми же самыми методами. К сожалению, не все СУБД выставляют эти методы в достаточно "кусочном" виде, пригодном для такой адаптации.

Answer (score 1):

Ну например так.

Вы находите группы «одинаковых» символов, и состовляете отображение символа на его группу. (Для оптимизации можно опустить одноэлементные группы.) Это делается один раз, до старта программы.

Затем проходите по символам строки. Для каждого из них у вас есть набор символов, на короый его можно заменить. Ваш код будет таким:

```
var sb = new StringBuilder(s);
var results = GetAllCombinations(sb, 0);
```

```
IEnumerable<string> GetAllCombinations(StringBuilder sb, int index)
{
    if (index >= sb.Length)
    {
        yield return sb.ToString();
        yield break;
    }
    char currC = sb[index];
    List<char> table = GetSimilarSymbols(currC);
    if (table == null) table = new List<char>() { currC };
    foreach (var c in table)
    {
        sb[index] = c;
        foreach (var s in GetAllCombinations(sb, index + 1))
            yield return s;
    }
    sb[index] = currC;
}
```

Comment: Я не уверен, но похоже, что вы идёте слева направо меняя символы=> в последовательности будет отсутствовать случай, когда поменялась лишь последняя буква

Comment: @iluxa1810: Почему не будет? В каждом рекурсивном вызове `GetAllCombinations` будет по одному элементу в `table`, кроме последнего.

Answer (score 0):

1. Один раз определить эталонные буквы.
2. Составить таблицу замен неэталонных букв эталонными.
3. Все слова в словаре заменить на написание через эталонные буквы.
4. Все неэталонные буквы в поступившем тексте заменить эталонными.
5. Осуществить обычный поиск по словарю (соответствие сейчас однозначное).